# How to change the delimiters

Tags: delimiters, txfonts

I use the package txfonts and I like the delimiters,I want to change them to those of Computer Modern. The difference is very clear between one and the other

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear: you like the TX fonts delimiters, but you want to change them?

Comment: @egreg I don't like the TX fonts delimiters. I want to change them